# Setting up django in windows

Tags: python, django, windows, django-admin, virtualenv

The short: none of the django install instructions seemed to apply to my windows system and I am hoping some one knows why

The long:
The django install instructions had me pulling my hair out bc . . .  I am on Windows (8, even!)

Nothing like this worked:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

but a generous stackoverflow post pointed out I should use **virtualenv**.  It would seem it helps manage environment variables like python path

**first lesson learned** starting the virtualenv is different in Windows.  This does not work:
http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#activate-script

Better to get to the dir you want to install django in and then use:

```
c:\awesomepath>[pathToActivate]\activate
```

ok now there is a prompt showing you are "in" the virtualenv.  But the standard command here did not work either:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I ended up using :

```
(virtualEnvName) c:\awesomepath>python [pathTodjango-admin]\django-admin.py startproject [prjName]
```

**Does any one know why the standard instructions did not work?  Did I do something wrong when setting up my virtual environment or does this look standard?**  I am especially confused as to why this did not work without a virtual environment.  In my numerous attempts, I did call the direct path to django-admin and I have python in my path.

[pulls hair out again]

At the very least pls tell me if I did this correctly so that others Windows knuckleheads like me can do this correctly in the future.

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but have you considered running an instance of Linux in a virtual machine? You can get Ubuntu for free and run it in VirtualBox for free. In my experience using Django with Windows is more trouble than it's worth considering how quickly a virtual machine can be set up. And this goes for much more than just Django.

Comment: AH!  I appreciate that notion.  Hate to say it, but i think i screwed up an interview bc I was NOT aware (until ~November) HOW EASY it is to use a virtual box so thank you for the reminder.

Do you have much experience using general python in Windows?  I wonder if many of my troubles would be resolved if I got used to virtualBox.

Comment: There's nothing quite like the ability to open up a terminal and just type `python` to get going :P. Honestly I haven't dug too far into python development on windows, but especially if you're going to be running a web server, you're much better off on Linux (I personally recommend Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS). Of course, if you want a GUI, then you'd want the regular flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: This isn't really an answer either, but I do have a youtube channel where I show how to use virtualenv to get going in django on windows. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txWYQhUac_Y